# Prove the sequence is perfect square

Tags: induction

**Question**

Given a sequence $a_0 = a_1 = 97\sqrt{2}$ and
$$\forall n   \space \space a_{n+1}= \frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}[a_n a_{n-1} + \sqrt{(a_n^2-2)(a_{n-1}^2-2)}]$$
Proof that
$$2+\sqrt{2+a_n\sqrt{2}}$$
is a perfect square

**My approach**

Use mathematical induction to prove that 
(base case are trivial, this is the inductive step)

$$2+\sqrt{2+a_na_{n-1}+\sqrt{(a_n^2-2)(a_{n-1}^2-2)}}$$
However, this does not hold true for all $a_n$, there seems to be an invariant from the initial value that makes it perfect square. Any hints would be appreciated.

Comment: Out of curiosity, where did you find this recurrence? Or did you come up with this?

Comment: @Marco Bellochi I found it in one of Mathematics Olympiad questions

Comment: Thanks for letting me know

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not an answer, but I want to share some of my findings and I cannot do it in a comment. Let $$x_n=2+\sqrt{2+a_n\sqrt{2}}$$ for $n=0,1,...$. Now it is easy to prove that indeed $x_0,x_1,x_2,x_3$ are perfect squares. But there is a precise relationship between $x_n$ for $n>2$ and it is $$\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}-\sqrt{x_{n-3}}$$ Now the base case for $k=3$ is trivial to verify. If by induction we suppose that then for $k=4,5,,...n$ we have  $$\sqrt{x_k}=\sqrt{x_{k-1}x_{k-2}}-\sqrt{x_{k-3}}$$ and also $$x_k \text{ is a perfect square}$$ then it remains to show that  $$\sqrt{x_{n+1}}=\sqrt{x_{n}x_{n-1}}-\sqrt{x_{n-2}}$$ which implies than that $x_{n+1}$ is a perfect square and by induction we are done. However the algebra is a bit messy, but I believe it could be a good line of attack.

Comment: This equation $\sqrt{x_n}=\sqrt{x_{n-1}x_{n-2}}-\sqrt{x_{n-3}}$ is not true. For example, $a_2 = (4*97^2 - 2)/\sqrt{2}$ and $a_3 = (8*97^3 - 6*97)/\sqrt{2}$

Comment: I specified for n>2

Comment: Hence base case is for n=3. For n=0,1,2 it is easy to verify that xn is a perfect square. Then for n=3, which is my base case, the relationship holds I believe

Comment: Indeed we have $\sqrt{x_3}=52$, $\sqrt{x_2}=14$, $\sqrt{x_1}=4$, $\sqrt{x_0}=4$ and obviously $14*4-4=52$

Comment: I am sorry. I mistook your $x_n$ for $a_n$.